# UIScrollview contents always on top

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to make my `UIScrollView` take up all the screen and have an image inside of it which the user can zoom, pan, etc. This all works. But, when then user taps the screen once, I want that on top of this `UIScrollView` an additional view appears with some information about the picture. The problem is that no matter what I do, the `UIScrollView`'s child ImageView is always on top. I have tried changing the order of the views in the xib, I have tried using `bringSubViewToFront` with no success. Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {       
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(flipViewSingleTap:)];  
    singleTapGesture.delegate = self;    

    self.flippedImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.flippedImage addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGesture];

    [singleTapGesture release];

    self.flippedImageView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1024, 768);
    self.flippedImageView.delegate = self;

    self.flippedMenuView.alpha = 0.0f;
}

- (IBAction)flipViewSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    flipItemsVisible = !flipItemsVisible;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.flippedMenuView];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f 
                          delay:0.0f 
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.flippedMenuView.alpha = flipItemsVisible ? 1.0f : 0.0f
              } 
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add this line to viewDidLoad:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.flippedMenuView];
```

(This assumes that self.view is the UIScrollView.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this does not help. if i add the flippedMenuView as a subview of the UIScrollView, it pans away from the screen if the user zooms in. The point of me adding it as a separate view on top was to make it "static" in terms of motion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` delegate method that ignores the menu view.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
  return ![touch.view isDescendantOfView:self.flippedMenuView];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but no, this didn't change anything.

Comment: What do you see if you add a `NSLog(@"%@", touch.view);` (and try with both always return `NO` and then `YES`)? is the `flippedView` and `flippedMenuView` views subviews in the same view?

Comment: I think the problem is not related to the touches. Even if I initially make the flippedMenuView visible, it is always portraid behind the scrolling image.

Comment: I know this is old and possibly solved, but UIScrollView already has gesture recognizers attached to it and "catches" certain touches. The above answer would help you narrow down the solution. I see you've already noticed how you needed to turn on interaction just to get the points. I'm dealing with scroll views right now, they're a bit intricate with the extra subviews and such. Annoying stuff not in the docs

Answer (score 0):

Turning on userInteraction for the image view isn't enough. Its default method for touchesMoved/Began are blank ( I think).

Make sure your own custom subclass of UIImageView is what the flippedImageView is. Overwrite those methods and send a delegate message (custom) that says something like "userTappedImageAt:".

If your subview handling just won't bring anything to the front, and your touches are working, grab the application delegate window [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] and add a subview to it, however it's probably safer to use a view so you can use convertPoint: from/to functions.

Most of what I told you can be inferred from reading the Views and Programming Guide, along with questions on SO with answers as to getting views on top.

You can always "roll your own" subviews to avoid unknown SDK recognizers.

Good luck,
Stephen